# Tracking resource changes in eclipse also in .metadata and .project

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I implemented a IResourceChangeListener in an eclipse plug-in. It monitors all the change events pretty well, but it only reports changes to project files itself.

Is it somehow possible to monitor changes to **.project** and **.metadata** files in the same way. I want to obtain a delta of changes to these folders in order to have a complete change set. It is not sufficient for me to add a PropertyChangeListener to Preferences.

It would be great if anybody had an answer. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). Are you writing your own Eclipse product or an RCP or just a plugin that can be installed into most any Eclipse product?

Comment: I'm writing a simple plugin that can be installed in most any Eclipse products. The problem is that resource changes or deltas do not include .project and .metadata. I would like to have a delta of these folders just as I have for the project folders.

Comment: .project is a file, not a folder, and it is a child delta of the project when it changes.  .metadata is not part of the workspace model, it is just a directory that is always under the workspace directory.